# error al usar app:srcCompat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app

Tengo un problema al usar srcCompat en el siguiente codigo

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp" />
```

el codigo con problemas es

> app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"

El error que tengo es:

```
To use VectorDrawableCompat, you need to set 'android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true'.
```

El principio del xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

ademas en el build.gradle lo tengo activado

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con añadir esto en tu botón flotante :

```
tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"
```

Si no funciona, despues de agregar `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` en tu gradle, ahora en la clase o clases que haces referencia a tu botón añade :

```
static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
```

Debe agregar esto a cada actividad en la que desee usar `VectorDrawables` en dispositivos inferiores a Android 5.

Comment: ingrese el codigo pero ingresando en logcat tengo estos problemas acabo de subirlos a la pagina añadir  y aun no se que puedan ser

Comment: cual de las dos opciones usaste?

Comment: la primera opción, pero reinicie android-studio luego para asegurarme que el error fuera del código y es hay que apareció este error

Comment: utiliza la segunda, si la primera no funciona, solo debes copiar y pegar el codigo

Comment: si ya me funciona gracias!! c;

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes configurado el soporte para usar graficos vectoriales, además si usas `compileSdkVersion 26`, debes tener una versión de AS 2.0+.

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Me parece más un problema de caché, ya que habilitar el soporte para gráficos vectoriales, se puede realizar dentro del `build.gradle`. esto para soportar el uso de estos gráficos en todos los sistemas operativos.